# how to have a caption on top of longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable

I want to have a longtable like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
\caption{my caption}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 
\hline 
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
.
.
.
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline

\label{variability_impl_mech}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

but when I try to compile this, I get this error: !Misplaced \noalign

when I write the caption after the last \hline, it works fine. I want to have the caption on top of my table but this error appears.

Comment: To start with, remove the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` instructions -- a `longtable` is automatically centered. Second, add a double backslash after `\caption{...}`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
\caption{my caption}\\    %%%%<===
\hline
```

and you should put the `\label` after `\caption`, which makes more sense.

Comment: As an addition to the original answer  using the label after caption should be as \caption{my caption} \label{my label}\\ not as \caption{my caption}\\  \label{my label}

Comment: For me it doesn't compile without `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead`. See @Benjamin McKay's answer.

Comment: In my current version of Miktex (and when pushed up to overleaf), compilation would stall and hang without adding the "\\" after the caption command.  Hopefully that will help others running into this problem in the current version.

Answer (score 26):

Another way: use head and first head:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
\caption{my caption}
\label{variability_impl_mech}
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 
%\hline 
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
.
.
.
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the only way it worked for me, with a \label after \caption.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with it, because I generate my tables with the library pandas from python. In this way.

```
print(tabla_1.to_latex(index = False, longtable=True))
```

But the problem is that pandas generate my longtables in this way:

```
\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
\toprule
                  Nombre &  No datos &  P. rango &  total\_isnull \\
\midrule
```

So I tried to put `\label`and `\caption` before `\toprule`, but it nevers compile. So my solution was change `\toprule` for `\hline` and then you'll have your compilation, example:

```
\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
\label{YourLabel}
\Caption{YourCaption}
\hline
                  Nombre &  No datos &  P. rango &  total\_isnull \\
\midrule
```

Comment: I create tables using `pandas` in the same way and I find things work properly when placing ```\caption{the caption}\label{the label}\\``` after the `\begin{longtable}` line as mentioned by @Herbert

Comment: `\toprule` requires the `booktabs` package I believe.