# Bicaption for longtables doesn't work

Tags: captions, longtable

I'm trying to use bicaption for longtable, but I get this error:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\caption ->\noalign 
                    \bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ...
l.26 \bicaption{Test}{Test}
                            \\
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}[2012/02/19 v3.2f]
\usepackage[list=off]{bicaption}[2011/10/30 v1.0a]

\captionsetup[bi-first]{bi-first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{bi-second}

\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-first}[]{
  \def\tablename{Preglednica}
  \def\figurename{Slika}}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-second}[]{
  \def\tablename{Table}
  \def\figurename{Figure}}

\date{12/20/15}

\begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{llllllll}
\bicaption{Test}{Test} \\
\label{test}
Test & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\\toprule
1 & 0 & 0.282468 & 0.275974 & 0.25 & 0.217532 & 0.292887 & 0.260465\\
2 & 0.282468 & 0 & 0.279236 & 0.2 & 0.24 & 0.054393 & 0.232558\\
3 & 0.275974 & 0.279236 & 0 & 0.24821 & 0.243437 & 0.221757 & 0.172093\\
4 & 0.25 & 0.2 & 0.24821 & 0 & 0.424979 & 0.158996 & 0.195349\\
5 & 0.217532 & 0.24 & 0.243437 & 0.424979 & 0 & 0.146444 & 0.204651\\
6 & 0.292887 & 0.054393 & 0.221757 & 0.158996 & 0.146444 & 0 & 0.255814\\
7 & 0.260465 & 0.232558 & 0.172093 & 0.195349 & 0.204651 & 0.255814 & 0
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

What could be wrong???

Thanks

Comment: It probably does not support longtable, the caption in longtable is not the usual caption construction so unless bicaption directly lists longtable support, it is probably a bit much to ask for. Hopefully someone else can tell you what is needed for it to work with longtable

Comment: The `bicaption` package documentation does not include an own compatibility list. It should work with all packages the main `caption` package is adapted to, at least that was my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh Axel just answered but this works for now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}[2012/02/19 v3.2f]
\usepackage[list=off]{bicaption}[2011/10/30 v1.0a]
\usepackage{booktabs}
\captionsetup[bi-first]{bi-first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{bi-second}

\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-first}[]{
  \def\tablename{Preglednica}
  \def\figurename{Slika}}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-second}[]{
  \def\tablename{Table}
  \def\figurename{Figure}}

\date{12/20/15}

\begin{document}
\let\oldcaption\caption
 \begin{longtable}{llllllll}
\multicolumn{8}{c}{%
\makebox[0pt]{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering
\let\caption\oldcaption
\expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{table}%
\bicaption{Test}{Test}}}} \\
\label{test}
Test & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\\toprule
1 & 0 & 0.282468 & 0.275974 & 0.25 & 0.217532 & 0.292887 & 0.260465\\
2 & 0.282468 & 0 & 0.279236 & 0.2 & 0.24 & 0.054393 & 0.232558\\
3 & 0.275974 & 0.279236 & 0 & 0.24821 & 0.243437 & 0.221757 & 0.172093\\
4 & 0.25 & 0.2 & 0.24821 & 0 & 0.424979 & 0.158996 & 0.195349\\
5 & 0.217532 & 0.24 & 0.243437 & 0.424979 & 0 & 0.146444 & 0.204651\\
6 & 0.292887 & 0.054393 & 0.221757 & 0.158996 & 0.146444 & 0 & 0.255814\\
7 & 0.260465 & 0.232558 & 0.172093 & 0.195349 & 0.204651 & 0.255814 & 0
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is working, but problem is that counting of tables is wrong. Counter is one more that it should be. How could this be corrected?

Comment: counter  is raised for two

Comment: @lobi oh sorry add `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` just before the `\bicaption`

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a bug in `bicaption`. Since the combination `bicaption`+`longtable` is not part of my pre-release test cases (yet) it could be that this has never worked and an additional adaption is necessary here.

I have just opened a ticket and will fix that ASAP:

https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/28/

**Update (2016-02-01)**

I fixed the bug by adding longtable support to `\bicaption`, it should be available on CTAN and as update for your TeX distribution soon.

**Update (2020-01-03)**

Starting with v3.4h of the `caption` package options cannot be used anymore prior to definition. Therefore `\captionsetup[bi-first]{bi-first}` and `\captionsetup[bi-second]{bi-second}` has to be done *after* `\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-first}...`, otherwise the document will not compile anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I use Benjamin and David's solution, and solve it by "use head and first head":

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
\caption{my caption}
\label{variability_impl_mech}
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\hline
% Your Table Contents
\end{longtable}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219145/200620 for details.