# Table number skips 1

Tags: tables, numbering, longtable

Consider this script:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
See \ref{tab:results}~tab and \ref{tab:moreresults}~tab.
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Results}
\label{tab:results}
\begin{longtable}{lr}
A & B \\
\end{longtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{More results}
\label{tab:moreresults}
\begin{longtable}{lr}
C & D \\
\end{longtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

It seems LaTeX has created a ghost table 2. What is wrong?

Comment: A `longtable` comes with its own `table` environment and therefore should not be wrapped into `\begin{table}...\end{table}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219138/35864 on how to use it with a caption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`longtable` need not be (and as you discovered should not be) nested inside a `table` environment.

To quote the page 1 of the [excellent documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf)

> The `longtable` package defines a new environment, `longtable`, which has most of  the features of the `tabular` environment, but produces tables which may be broken
>   by TeX's standard page-breaking algorithm. It also shares some features with
>   the `table` environment. In particular it uses the same counter, `table`, and has a
>   similar `\caption` command. Also, the standard `\listoftables` command lists
>   tables produced by either the `table` or `longtable` environments.

That means that for most intents and purposes `longtable` has its own `table` environment already built in.

If a `longtable` is nested in a `table` the `table` counter is stepped up twice (and maybe other even worse things happen...).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
See \ref{tab:results}~tab and \ref{tab:moreresults}~tab.

\begin{longtable}{lr}
\caption{Results}\label{tab:results}\\*
A & B \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{lr}
\caption{More results}\label{tab:moreresults}\\*
C & D \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

should do the right thing.

[image: The screenshot shows two tables "Table 1" and "Table 2"]

That means that `longtable`s can't easily float, but that is probably for the better.

Note the `\\*` (or `\\`) after the `\caption`, which are usually not needed in a `table`. See also [how to have a caption on top of longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219138/35864).

*edit* Changed to `\\*` after `\caption` in light of [page split between longtable caption and table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477409/35864)