# Page split between longtable caption and table

Tags: captions, page-breaking, longtable

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

another paragraph

another paragraph

another paragraph

another paragraph

anoteher paragraph

another paragraph

another paragraph

%anoteher paragraph

%another paragraph

\begin{longtable}{lr}
  \caption{long table}\\
  A&B\\
  c&D
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, the caption of the long table is on one page, while the table itself on another page:

[image]

How do I avoid such an awkward situation?

**Comment on answers**

An additional problem is introduced when using `\hline` immediately after the caption:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{needspace}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]

    another paragraph

    another paragraph

    another paragraph

    another paragraph

    anoteher paragraph

    another paragraph

    another paragraph

    %anoteher paragraph

    %another paragraph
    %\Needspace{5\baselineskip}
    \begin{longtable}{lr}
      \caption{some table}\\*
      \hline
      A&B\\
      c&D\\
      E&F
      \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Even when using `\\*` we revert to the initial state of affairs:

[image]

It appears the problem can be solved by uncommenting the line `%\Needspace{5\baselineskip}`

However, it seems some manual adjustment is needed to `\Needspace` in the case of multiline captions.

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

another paragraph

another paragraph

another paragraph

another paragraph

anoteher paragraph

%another paragraph

%another paragraph

%anoteher paragraph

%another paragraph
\Needspace{5\baselineskip}
\begin{longtable}{lr}
  \caption{\lipsum[1][1-3]}\\*
  \hline
  A&B\\
  c&D\\
  E&F
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The result is again the same:

[image]

This case is fixed by changing `5` in `\Needspace{5\baselineskip}` to `6`.

Comment: Have you tried `\\*` instead of ``\\`` after the `\caption`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati, it worked. What is the difference?

Comment: From the documentation: "`\\*`: The same as ```\\``` but disallows a page break after the row."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `\\*` instead of `\\` after the `\caption`.  From the manual:

> `\\*`: The same as `\\` but disallows a page break after the row.

---

`longtable` has some macros to control headings (cf. manual section 3).  Depending on your use-case, have a look at `\endhead` or `\endfirsthead`.  This code works for me:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

another paragraph

another paragraph

another paragraph

another paragraph

anoteher paragraph

\begin{longtable}{lr}
  \caption{\lipsum[1][1-3]}\\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  A&B\\
  c&D\\
  E&F
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Please see a comment to your answer in my post.

Comment: @Viesturs - See my updated answer.

Comment: `\endfirsthead` helps, especially convenient when the longtable has multiline headers.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to have at least 3 rows of the `longtable` to show up before considering a page break to be unacceptable, you could load the `needspace` package and issue the directive

```
\Needspace{5\baselineskip}
```

immediately before `\begin{longtable}`. That way, unless there are at least 5 lines of text still free at the bottom of the page, the `longtable` will start at the top of the next page.

Why `5\baselineskip`? Because the longtable's caption and the blank line between the caption and the start of the body of the text take up 2 more lines.

Comment: Please see a comment to your answer in my post.

Comment: @Viesturs -  You wrote, "it seems some manual adjustment is needed to [the argument of] `\Needspace` in the case of multiline captions." Indeed: I had based my answer on the information you provided. If that information doesn't apply, a different, and quite likely larger, value should be used as the argument of `\Needspace`.