# How to fit large text in rows of longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have 4 columns with long text in each column. The text overflows to next column if tried below code:
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfb8K.png)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{p{2.8cm} p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}}& 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TForth column}}\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multirow{4}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{techniqued}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{issues}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{future}}\\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

\multirow{4}{*} textttttttttttttttttttttttt & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}][1]][1]
```

I want to restrict long text to each specific column.

Comment: Maybe unsurprisingly, LaTeX has *not* been programmed to "know" how to line-break the string `textttttttttttttttttttttttt`. In your opinion, how and where should this string be line-broken? Please advise.

Comment: Try replacing `texttttttttttttttttttttttttttt` with some real words that have spaces between them: you will find that LaTeX will keep everything within the space for that column in that case. If you need to tell LaTeX exactly where to break the line, then you can use `\newline`.

Comment: Off-topic but still relevant: A `longtable` environment should never, ever be encased in a `center` environment.

Comment: @mico: why not? If this is an important piece of information to help this user, perhaps explain why, or give a link to an explanation. This user came here for help.

Comment: @rbrignall because `longtable` does the centering of its contents itself and `center` gives inconsistent spacing above and below the `longtable`.

Comment: @rbrignall - The `longtable` environment centers its contents automatically. Encasing a `longtable` in a `center` environment achieves nothing except that it inserts unneeded and unwanted whitespace above and below the `longtable` material. Quite a few postings on this site make this point; see, for instance, my comment under the posting [how to have a caption on top of longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219138/5001).

Comment: Don't tell me that, tell the questioner that!

Comment: @rbrignall - The OP gets to see all comments. Hopefully they'll have an effect.

Comment: Yes, I know the OP gets to see all comments. My point is that you should never, ever, tell someone what not to do without offering some kind of explanation (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8467/empathy-for-those-who-dont-know-latex-well?cb=1).

Comment: @Mico @ rbrignall.... I think the question is not about centering a text in longtable.

Comment: @CaseMsee - I deliberately started my comment with the word "off-topic", as I was well aware that nesting `center` and `longtable` environments was *not* the main subject of your query. Unfortunately, that comment subsequently got hijacked and blown out of all proportion. Anyway, do please provide some information about how *you* believe the string `textttttttttttttttttttttttt` (or all other strings whose widths exceed the width of the cell) should be line-broken.

Answer (score 0):

- Syntax of `\multirow{4}{*} textttttttttttttttttttttttt` is wrong. Missing are curly braces around `textttttttttttttttttttttttt`: `\multirow{4}{*}{textttttttttttttttttttttttt}`
- If you like to have `multirow` cel has the same width as prescribed for columns where it is, than you you can exploit new options of `multirow` caption: `\multirow{4}{=}{textttttttttttttttttttttttt}`
- real word on place of `textttttttttttttttttttttttt` is not natural word, which is consider in hyphenation rules, than you can insert hyphenation point manually. For example: `text\-ttttt\-tttt\-tttttt\-ttt\-ttttt`
- It is not clear why you use `\multirow` cell. Its contents is only move below and overwrite rows below it.

Off-topic:

- use of the `\thead` command from `makecell` package can simplify to write column headers
- for numbers in the last two columns seems to be the use of the `S` column type defined in `siunitx` package more appropriate than `p` type.

Considering above, the resulted table is:

[image]

(red lines marked page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{longtable, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{ *{2}{p{2.8cm}} 
                       *{2}{S[table-format=3.6]}}
\caption{A sample long table.} 
\label{tab:long} \\
    \hline 
\thead{First\\ column}
    & \thead{Second\\ column}
                        & {\thead{Third\\ column}}
                                    & {\thead{Forth\\ column}}  \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{A sample long table -- continued from previous page} \\ 
    \hline
\thead{First\\ column}
    & \thead{Second\\ column}
                        & {\thead{Third\\ column}}
                                    & {\thead{Forth\\ column}}  \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on next page}} \\ 
\endfoot
    \hline \hline
\endlastfoot

text\-ttttt\-tttt\-tttttt\-ttt\-ttttt
    & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```